How to exclude process by PID while using Processes Snapshot (ps)
I want to get snapshot of the current processes and exclude all associated with Docker (docker itself, containerd and containerd-shim-runc-v2).

I've remembered my own serverfault question, and there's the answer:
ps --ppid 2 -o pid,cmd

In my case I've changed ppid to 1.
